# Any way not to support IE11 about Outlook Office Add-in?

Tags: javascript, outlook-addin, office-addins

Currently we're developing Microsoft Outlook Office Add-in. Although we almost finished the implementation phase, we got rejected by the app review phase. According to the feedback from the reviewer, when users take advantage of Outlook on the web and open our Add-in on Internet Explorer 11(IE11), it does not work well.(An exception occurs on browser console) However, since the exception does not occur on Chrome, Edge, and Safari, I would like to explicitly eliminate IE11 from supported browsers (and pass the app review).

Question: Are there any ways not to support IE11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```js
// `document.documentMode` is a number in IE 5+
// and `undefined` in all other browsers
var isIe = !!document.documentMode

if (isIe) {
  // replace with whatever logic you want to implement for IE users
  document.body.textContent = 'Sorry, IE not supported'
} else {
  // replace with logic for non-IE users
  app.init()
}
```